# a question about field theory and polynomials

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Hello all I was given this question in my field theory class on which I would certainly appreciate the help: I am given a field F of characteristic p ($ ch(F) > 0 $) and this polynomial

$ f(x) = x^p - x -a $ such that $ a \in F^* $

I am asked to show that if $ g,h \in F[x] $ are irreducible factors of the polynomial f then
$ deg(g)=deg(h) $

All I was able to do was to show that the derivative of the polynomial is
$ f'(x) = px^{p-1}-1 = -1$

because p is the characteristic and this necessarily shows that f and f' are coprime but I have no idea how to really proceed to the claim I am asked to prove. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Something is missing, there is no condition put on $g$ and $h$ so you can't conclude anything about them.

Comment: Maybe he means $f=gh$?

Comment: Ah that makes more sense now.

Comment: sorry I needed to mention g and h are irreducible factors of the polynomial f in question. I added missing info thank you for noticing

Comment: Consider the splitting field of $f$, in there the galois group must permute roots, so it must permute the irreducible factors, so they must have the same degree.  Something like that is the argument you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @GregoryGrant I was thinking in terms of splitting fields but I cannot go further unfortunately by myself because my galois theory is not proficient enough sorry

Comment: @zbigniew2015 jgon's argument might be easier, since in my argument you probably need to show $f$ is irreducible.

Comment: Wait my argument doesn't work since it can factor without having roots. I'm sorry. *facepalm* I deleted the comment so as not to trip up other people in the future, might be useful for characterizing the splitting field though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you already solved this, but I felt like I should explain for anyone in the future since I deleted my original comment.

To expand on my comment (since deleted) and my second comment, notice that if $\alpha$ is a root of $f$, then $\alpha+i$ is also a root for $i$ in the characteristic subfield, $\Bbb{F}_p$ since $(\alpha+i)^p-\alpha-i -a=\alpha^p-\alpha-a+i^p-i=0+i-i=0$ since $i\in \Bbb{F}_p$. Therefore if $f$ has a root in a field, then it has at least $p$ distinct roots. Since it is a polynomial of degree $p$ these are all the roots. Thus if the polynomial has one root in a field, it factors completely.

Then hint:
What is the degree of the splitting field?

> We now have that the splitting field of the polynomial has degree $d$ over the base field where $d$ is the degree of any irreducible factor of $f$, since adjoining the root of any irreducible factor gives the splitting field. This is what we wished to show.

Comment: Thank you @jgon helpful indeed

Comment: @zbigniew2015 No problem, glad to be helpful